# Python function call inside string formatting throws an error

Tags: python

```
a = ";"
b = ["foo","bar"]
c = f"{a.join(b)}" #works properly "foo;bar"
print(c)

d = {"a":a, "b":b}
c = "{a.join(b)}".format(**d) #CRASH
print(c)
```

Error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'join(b)'

Is there any way to make the second version work? Call .format on a string and have .join work.

Comment: No, you can't use f-string syntax outside of f-strings. `str.format` only supports [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings), not arbitrary expression evaluation.

Comment: `c = str.join(*d.values())`. The best way to do this, though, depends on why the delimiter and list of values are being supplied by a `dict` and whether you can specify them somehow differently, and what *larger* string you are trying to build, as the result of `f'{a.join(b)}'` isn't any different from `a.join(b)` alone.

Comment: `a.join(b)` is just an example, basically there is a long manually written string read from a file that could use the `f"{a.some_function()}"` formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `format` function is not a full-blown python interpreter, it can only access the properties of the given objects, but not execute code. If you want to format your string with the `format` syntax, you can do it in the following way:

```py
a = ";"
b = [ "foo", "bar" ]
c = "{}".format(a.join(b))
print(c)
```

Comment: `"{}".format(a.join(b))` won't really help me but i imagine saying that it can't be done counts as accepted answer

Comment: these are the limitations of the language, frankly, I can't do anything about it